# Can I create my own sequence in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, sequence

Can I create my own sequence in [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29), like I have a database sequence and I have to add 2 characters before the sequence?

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own identifier generator. Have a look at this [blog post](http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/?p=43) which is basically showing how to do something similar to what you're looking for (unless I misundertsood the question):

> #### Custom Hibernate Sequence Generator for Id field
>
> I have a table with a primary key in
>   the format M001, M002 etc (lets not
>   think about what happens after M999
>   for now). I’m using Hibernate
>   Annotations, and I found a great way
>   of generating the Primary Key value
>   for new Records:
>
> First I created a database sequence to
>   use. Then I implemented
>   `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator`;
>
> ```
> public class StockCodeGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
>
>     private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StockCodeGenerator.class);
>
>     public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
>             throws HibernateException {
>
>         String prefix = "M";
>         Connection connection = session.connection();
>         try {
>
>             PreparedStatement ps = connection
>                     .prepareStatement("SELECT nextval ('seq_stock_code') as nextval");
>
>             ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
>             if (rs.next()) {
>                 int id = rs.getInt("nextval");
>                 String code = prefix + StringUtils.leftPad("" + id,3, '0');
>                 log.debug("Generated Stock Code: " + code);
>                 return code;
>             }
>
>         } catch (SQLException e) {
>             log.error(e);
>             throw new HibernateException(
>                     "Unable to generate Stock Code Sequence");
>         }
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Then, in my entity class, I simply
>   annotate the id field like this:
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GenericGenerator(name="seq_id", strategy="my.package.StockCodeGenerator")
> @GeneratedValue(generator="seq_id")
> @Column(name = "stock_code", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
> public String getStockCode() {
>     return this.stockCode;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. With Date and Calender

```
 public class StockCodeGenerator
 implements IdentifierGenerator
 {
 private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StockCodeGenerator.class);


 public StockCodeGenerator() {}

 public int generateCustId()
 {
 Random random = new Random();
 return random.nextInt(100);
 }


 public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
 throws HibernateException
 {
 String prefix = "Custom_String";
 Connection connection = session.connection();
 System.out.println(session.connection());


 Date date = new Date();

 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 return prefix + "_" + generateCustId() + "_" + calendar.get(1);
 }
 }
```

And then use it in your @GenericGenerator annotation

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="seq_id",strategy="com.mvc.StockCodeGenerator.
StockCodeGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator="seq_id")
```